# "Using 'BCP(Bulk Copy Program)/Bulk Insert' can we send data from One server1 database to another server2 Database..?"

Tags: sql-server, msbi

Using BCP (Bulk Copy Program) / bulk insert; can we send data from `server1` to another `server2` database?

```
      SERVER_1                               SERVER_2             
         |                                      |
     DATBASE_1                              DATABASE_2
         |                                      |
    TABLE_1 (5 COLUMNS)
         |_____________________________> TABLE_1 (ID, NAME)            
         |_____________________________> TABLE_2 (AGE, GENDER)     
         |_____________________________> TABLE_3 (ADDR)
```

Comment: Yes. What problem are you having? Please expand on your question. Type `BCP /?` into a command prompt and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Run BCP once to output all 5 columns of Table_1, then run BCP 3 times to load the 3 different tables on Server_2, using 3 different format files to pick which columns to load into each table. See the [BCP Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) documentation for more info, and there's a lot of info on using [format files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/format-files-for-importing-or-exporting-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) too.